# How to avoid union in SQL Server for this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a union statement in the query which needs to eliminated as its performance hit because of the millions of records found in below tables.

How can I achieve using left join so that performance is not compromised?

The difference between 2 select statements here is that when `M.Id<>0` then `U.UserId` is used in 1st `SELECT`statement and when `M.Id=0` then `''` is returned in 2nd `SELECT` statement as I'm not using `User` table in  it . I'm using SQL Server 2016

```
Select 
    U.UserId, A.ActivityPlace 
From 
    UserTable U
Inner Join 
    MasterTable M ON M.Id = U.UserId
Inner Join 
    ActivityTable A ON A.ActivityID = M.UserId
Where 
    M.Id <> 0

Union

Select 
    '', A.ActivityPlace 
From 
    MasterTable M 
Inner Join 
    ActivityTable A ON A.ActivityID = M.UserId
Where 
    M.Id = 0
```

Comment: Are you certain you need `union`, not `union all`? union all has less performance impact. If you do need `union` (which uses distinct) then no `join` solution will help

Answer (score 1):

You can try to move condition into the `CASE` expression.

```
Select 
    CASE WHEN M.Id<>0 THEN U.UserId ELSE 0 END AS UserId
    ,A.ActivityPlace 
From 
    MasterTable AS M
    INNER JOIN ActivityTable AS A ON A.ActivityID = M.UserId
    LEFT JOIN UserTable AS U ON M.Id = U.UserId
;
```

Since you didn't show how the tables are related, it may or may not produce correct result. It is hard to tell without knowing how the tables are related.

Comment: :I have already shown the relationship between the table with the help of Inner join. What else information needed. Let me know

Comment: @nagaraja, it would be nice to know the type of relations: 1:1, 1:M, 1:0 or 1 ; what fields are unique. Do it for each `ON` clause in your query. For example, `M.Id = U.UserId` - `M.id` is unique, `U.UserId` is unique, for each `M.Id` there can be at most 1 row `U.UserId` or none rows, i.e. relation is 1:0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

In that first query you get userid, in secon query you won't get userid.
Hence this 2 set of result is unique. so you can use union all.

```
Select U.UserId, A.ActivityPlace From UserTable U
Inner Join MasterTable  M ON M.Id=U.UserId
Inner Join ActivityTable A ON A.ActivityID=M.UserId
Where M.Id<>0

Union all

Select '', A.ActivityPlace From MasterTable  
M Inner Join ActivityTable A ON A.ActivityID=M.UserId
Where M.Id=0
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but it was my first thought: the original query's UNION could be slow because a UNION implies the need to sort and deduplicate the results, which, with a large result set, could easily be what's slowing down the query. A UNION ALL does not need to sort a potentially massive result set to de-duplicate. (Of course, the real answer here is "look at the query plan and find out what's taking the time"...)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do below

```
Select 
U.UserId, A.ActivityPlace 
From 
UserTable U
Inner Join 
MasterTable M ON (M.Id = U.UserId or M.Id = 0)
Inner Join 
ActivityTable A ON A.ActivityID = M.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would recommend:

```
Select U.UserId, A.ActivityPlace 
From MasterTable M left join
     UserTable U  
     on M.Id = U.UserId and m.id <> 0 left join
     ActivityTable A 
     on A.ActivityID = M.UserId;
```

This is not 100% equivalent to your query.  But with some assumptions:

- The `UNION` is not actually eliminating duplicates.
- `NULL` is a reasonable replacement for `''`.
- All but `0` user ids match

Then it should do what you want.  Actually, for the third condition, you could add:

```
where m.id = 0 or u.userid is not null
```

Actually, I assume that the special treatment for `m.id = 0` is simply because there is no user.  In that case, you just want `left join`s:

```
Select m.Id as UserId, A.ActivityPlace 
From MasterTable M left join
     UserTable U  
     on M.Id = U.UserId left join
     ActivityTable A 
     on A.ActivityID = M.UserId;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a union statement in the query which needs to eliminated as its
> performance hit because of the millions of records found in below
> tables.
>
> How can I achieve using left join so that performance is not
> compromised?

Unfortunately you did not provide any *useful information*, beside the fact that you have millions of records in some tables.

Here is something that would have helped us reproduce your problem and work out a possible solution:

- posting the full structure of the tables including indexes
- showing some sample data
- posting an example showing expected results

The obvious answer is: check the **execution plan** and if you don't understand it, post it along with the information mentioned above.

I am afraid that the answers you've got are speculative. **In spite of the best efforts of participants there is no guarantee that any of these answers will address your performance problem adequately**. There is simply not enough information.

The replies you've got are quite telling:

- "You can try to move condition into the CASE expression"
- "I think I would recommend"
- "I think you can do below"

Don't blame the members, you didn't give enough useful details so all they can do is **guess**.

One tip anyway: check your **indexes**, especially on the fields that are **JOIN**ed together. Since you are using SQL Server you can have a look at this guide for example: [Make Sure All JOIN Columns are Indexed](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3207/make-sure-all-join-columns-are-indexed/). This advice is equally valid for other relational DBMSes, although each has its own query optimizer and peculiarities.

I am actually surprised that nobody asked you about your **indexes**. Very often, it is indeed possible to rewrite an existing SQL statement in a way that makes it more performant. But you have to go to the root of the problem and consider the lower layers too, that is the data.

In simplified terms, if you have no index, and barring any cache or optimization tips, the database engine has to do a **full table scan** to get the results. If you have lots of records, that obviously takes time. If you join tables, the load further increases. The solution: good table structure, a sound data model and proper indexes.

An index is not a magic bullet though, if you have a poor table structure it will not be as effective as it should be.

If that still doesn't help, then I would suggest that you either add more details or post the question again later with all the relevant details. As a guideline: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

UNION command is a costly operation.
Reason:

1. It has to fully execute one select query
2. fetch the rows into the cache, then do a deduplicate
3. Repeat this operation for second query
4. Now merge both the results of the deduped query and again do a deduplicate on over all query.

The trick here is to make this union avoid due a deduplicate.

Solution:

1. Apply DISTINCT to both of your SELECT queries. Again BOTH of the select queries.
2. Instead of UNION have UNION ALL.

Note: This method should be used only when Union of both SQL does not produce duplicates. In my case, the record set was drastically reduced after distinct. Union All was just used to merged the 2 sets.

A query which took 1 min got completed in 9 seconds. This query was publishing data directly to a web portal used by a public sector. Every second matters to a website. The objective is to make Union to avoid debups instead distinct will take care of it

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. It also doesn't correctly simulate `UNION`.  `UNION` would remove duplicates across result sets. This method would still allow duplicates if both result sets contain identical rows

Comment: @MartinSmith Agreed. Not only that, but distinct on each is also not a zero-cost operation.

Comment: @MartinSmith it does answers the question. According to the question the query produces 2 different data set. Union is used just to merge the result of 2 SQL. Union is really not used here for deduplicate. Please check my updated comments at the end. Union should not be used if there are not duplicates, as it basically tries to do a comparison.